# Erro ao iniciar projeto com React Native Expo

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, expo

Tenho a versão 8.12.0 do NodeJS instalado no Debian 9, então fiz a instalação do Expo com o comando `npm install -g expo-cli`, que ao final retornou as seguintes alertas: [image: Alertas ao instalar Expo, via NPM]

Ignorando isso criei um projeto com o comando `expo init NomeProjeto`. Até ai tudo corre sem problemas, porém quando tento iniciar o projeto com `expo start` o processo é abortado retornando os seguintes erros: [image: Erros ao iniciar projeto Expo]

O que pode estar ocasionando esses erros, e como solucioná-los?

Answer (score -1):

Cara, tente utilizar o boilerplate create-react-native-app. 
Quando uso o expo gosto de usar com o yarn , então ficaria:
yarn create react-native-app nomeDoProjeto.

E para rodar o projeto:
yarn start

Esses comandos do expo eu nunca utilizei.

Se não tiver o yarn instalado :
https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/install/#debian-stable

Comment: Já descobri o problema, o projeto não estava sendo inicializado por falta de permissão no diretório, mudei e funcionou.